# Terraform helm_release fails on set labels

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I wish to set labels inside a Helm chart using the Terraform helm_release resource with a helpers function.

When using the chart values there are no issues, as seen here:

values.yaml

```
mylabels:
  name: "foo"
  type: "boo"
```

_helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "aws.labels" -}}
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.mylabels }}
{{ $k }}: {{ $v | quote }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

deployment.yaml

```
metadata:
  labels:
  {{- include "aws.labels" . | trim | nindent 4 }}
```

But when values are passed in from the helm_release resource it fails.

```
  set {
    name  = "mylabels"
    value = yamlencode(var.aws_tags) 
  }
```

The output values for the above is:

```
  + set {
      + name  = "mylabels"
      + value = <<-EOT
            "Environment": "123"
            "Owner": "xyz"
        EOT
    }
```

Which generates error:

```
│ Error: template: aws-efs-csi-driver/templates/controller-deployment.yaml:9:6: executing "aws-efs-csi-driver/templates/controller-deployment.yaml" at <include "aws.tags" .>: error calling include: template: aws-efs-csi-driver/templates/_helpers.tpl:68:27: executing "aws.tags" at <.Values.mylabels>: range can't iterate over 
│ "Environment": "123"
│ "Owner": "xyz"
```

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated :-)

## Solution

Thank you @jordanm that worked :~)

Comment: One thing to note is that most of these labels are immutable once applied.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to mention the best answer, please accept and upvote the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

When using `set` in this way, it's the same as `--set` on the helm cli. You can't provide a yaml value that includes multiple values and must set each individually.

```
  set {
    name  = "mylabels.Environment"
    value = var.aws_tags["Environment"] 
  }
  set {
    name  = "mylabels.Owner"
    value =  var.aws_tags["Owner"]
  }
```

You may also be able the `dynamic` feature of terraform to iterate over your `aws_tags` variable:

```
dynamic "set" {
  for_each = var.aws_tags
  
  content {
    name = "mylabels.${set.key}"
    value = set.value
  }
}
```